# Using generics and trying to get rid of the unsafe operations warning

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

Here is my code, but I keep getting the "Note: LinkedListAdd.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations." I'm trying to do what I can to get rid of it, but nothing seems to be working. The base class compiles fine and has no warning, and the check seems to be coming from the add all method. Any ideas?

```
public class LinkedListAdd<E extends Comparable <E> > extends LinkedList<E>
{
  public LinkedListAdd()
  {
     super();
  }

  public <E extends Comparable<E> > boolean addAll(final int index, final E[] array)
  {
     if(index < 0 || index > this.size())
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds");
     if(array == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Null array");

     Node nn = null; 
     for(int y = array.length - 1; y >= 0; y--)
     {
        nn = new Node(array[y], null);
        if(this.size() == 0)
        {
           this.head.next = nn;
           this.size += 1;
        }
        else
        {
           Node cur = this.head.next, prev = null;
           for(int x = 0; x < index; x++)
           {
              prev = cur;
              cur = cur.next;
           }
           if(prev == null)
           {
              nn.next = cur;
              this.head.next = nn;
              this.size += 1;
           }
           else
           {
              prev.next = nn;
              nn.next = cur;
              this.size += 1;
           }
        }
     }
     if(nn == null)
        return false;
     return true;
  }

}//end class LinkedListSort
```

Here is the base class

```
  public class LinkedList<E extends Comparable <E> >
  {
     protected static class Node<E extends Comparable <E> >
     {
        public E data;
        public Node<E> next;

        public Node()
        {
           this.next = null;
           this.data = null;
        }// end DVC

        public Node(final E data, final Node<E> next)
        {
           this.next = next;
           this.data = data;
        }// end EVC
     }// end class Node

     protected Node <E> head;
     protected int size;

     public LinkedList()
     {
        this.head = new Node<>();
        this.size = 0;
     }

     public void clear()
     {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
     }// end clear

     public int size(){return this.size;}

     public void addFirst(final E data)
     {
        this.head.next = new Node<>(data, this.head.next);
        size ++;
     }// end

     public String toString()
     {
        String temp = "List size: " + this.size;
        if(this.head.next == null)
           return temp += "\nEmpty List";

        else
        {
           temp += "\n";
           Node<E> cur = head.next;
           while(cur != null)
           {
              temp += cur.data + " ";
              cur = cur.next;
           }
           return temp;
        }// end else

     }// end toString

  }// end class
```

Comment: Is the Node class generic?

Comment: Could you include the code for Node?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I just added the base class

Comment: For starters, it definitely looks like you need to refer to `Node<E>`, not just `Node`...

Comment: I tried that, using Node<E> and I get this error

LinkedListAdd.java:21: error: incompatible types: Node<E#1> cannot be converted to Node<E#2>
            this.head.next = nn;
                             ^
  where E#1,E#2 are type-variables:
    E#1 extends Comparable<E#1> declared in method <E#1>addAll(int,E#1[])
    E#2 extends Comparable<E#2> declared in class LinkedListAdd @LouisWasserman

Comment: Ah, you definitely also need to get rid of `<E extends Comparable<E> >` in the declaration of the `addAll` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of things I'd recommend doing; firstly I'd add methods for get/set on your head/next/size/data and make those fields private

With regards to your generics;

the method signature should be

```
public boolean addAll(final int index, final E[] array)
```

and your declarations for nodes in that method need to be

```
Node<E> node
```